# add customer to parallel plesk

Tags: centos, plesk, parallels

i have plesk 10.1.1 install in centos 5 when i want to add a customer i got this error

Error: system user update is failed: unable to create system user: usermng: PAM password change failed: 24, Failed preliminary check by password service

i searched manay times and i have no idea what to do

tnx

Comment: Sounds like the password you supplied isn't strong enough, it's not letting you use it.

Comment: Thanks for reply but iam suing strong password but error is still there!

Answer (score 1):

We got this fix and we wrote an article (in Spanish) with all the related info in http://www.hackingballz.com/articulos/104/1/Plesk-PAM-Error-system-user-update-is-failed-Unable-to-create-system-user/Page1.html

Basically, you should replace the passwd and the system-auth with the configuration that we publish and it will start working. Tested in 3 different servers with those errors and all are working properly.